# Brunch build tool error while building react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, brunch

I am getting error while building react component using brunch build.
what is this error about?

```
 error: Compiling of js/assets/jss/material-dashboard-pro-react/views/userProfileStyles.jsx failed. L5:4 js/assets/jss/material-dashboard-pro-react/views/userProfileStyles.jsx: Unexpected token 
     3 |   cardTitle,
     4 |   cardIconTitle: {
   > 5 |     ...cardTitle,
       |     ^
     6 |     marginTop: "15px",
     7 |     marginBottom: "0px",
     8 |     "& small": {
```

and got this error also

```
14:44:44 - error: Compiling of js/components/Accordion/Accordion.jsx failed. L22:15 Unexpected token 
     20 |     };
     21 |   }
   > 22 |   handleChange = panel => (event, expanded) => {
        |                ^
     23 |     this.setState({
     24 |       active: expanded ? panel : -1
     25 |     });
```

Comment: That is called spread syntax and you most likely need to use [babel-brunch](https://github.com/babel/babel-brunch) with the [stage 3](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-stage-3) preset to be able to use it.

Comment: @Tholle Thanks for the answer. I installed both using npm install  and configured. like this 

`plugins: {
    babel: {
      presets: ["es2015", "react", "env", "stage-3"],
      // Do not use ES6 compiler in vendor code
      ignore: [/vendor/]
    }
  },`

But I am getting errors

Comment: You're welcome! Great, spread syntax seems to be working now. You are now getting errors for class properties, which is a [stage 2 proposal](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-stage-2.html). Try `"stage-2"` instead of `"stage-3"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting errors for [spread syntax](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread/) and [class properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties/).

You could install [babel-brunch](https://github.com/babel/babel-brunch) and a preset that contains both spread syntax and class properties, like the [`stage-2` preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-stage-2.html).